# Check if update query affected row or not

Tags: java, mysql, sql

If I want to select stuff in my database I can just executeQuery in a ResultSet and return that to see what I got. But how do I do checks if I want to insert or update rows?
How can I see what the db returned? If it affected anything?

```
public static boolean doUpdate(String statement) {
    openConnection();
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(statement);
        closeConnection();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(DBhandler.class.getName()+"\n"+ex);
        closeConnection();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried to give the function a boolean return value, but the code in try will continue no matter if the update/insert worked or not.

Comment: Doesn't [Statement.executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) already return the number of affected rows by your update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `executeUpdate` command returns the number of the affected rows. Keep that number and return true if at least one row was affected. Furthermore you should close your connection in a finally block, so even an exception occurs, the `closeConnection()` will be executed. Take a look at the below code.

```
public static boolean doUpdate(String statement) {
    boolean result = false;
    openConnection();
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeUpdate(statement) > 0;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(DBhandler.class.getName()+"\n"+ex);
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This will return false no matter what..?

Comment: Aha! it was because you run executeUpdate twice in your example! works superb now :) thanks

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

The [`executeUpdate` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-) returns the number of rows affected for appropriate SQL statements executed.

> Returns:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

```
int rows = executeUpdate(statement);
```

Then you can look at `rows` to see if it's `0`, and return a `boolean` appropriately.

Comment: I just tried this, even though the update query works, it returns 0 in my row variable??